# Isolate x in an exponential function?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

I have $x=2^x-1$. How do I isolate x? I tried to take the log of both sides of $x-1=2^x$, but then there's a $ln(x-1)$.

Comment: You cannot isolate $x$. Either you need numerical methods or the lambert-w-function.

Comment: I'd suggest that it doesn't admit a "nice" solution, that is one that you can give explicitly but only numerical ones. Though $x = 0$ is a solution.

Comment: ... and $x=1$ is another and the exponential is convex so there are at most two solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two trivial solutions: $x=0,x=1$.  There are no other real solutions.

---

For complex numbers:

Solving with the Lambert W function, I get

$$x-1=2^x$$

$x-1=u$

$$u=2^{u+1}$$

$$u=2e^{\ln(2)u}$$

$$ue^{-\ln(2)u}=2$$

$$-\ln(2)ue^{-\ln(2)u}=-2\ln(2)=-\ln(4)$$

$$-\ln(2)u=W(-\ln(4))$$

$$u=\frac{W(-\ln(4))}{-\ln(2)}$$

$$x=\frac{W(-\ln(4))}{-\ln(2)}+1$$

where $W(z)$ is the inverse of $ze^z$ and $e$ is Euler's number.  Choosing different branches will give you different answers, and two of the branches should admit $x=0,x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Already said, but if you are supposed to find the solutions to the equation: Show that $2^x-(1+x)$ is strictly convex (2nd derivative strictly positive), that there are two evident solutions and conclude.

Comment: 2nd derivate is strictly positive. How are the solutions evident? Trial and error?

Comment: Yes, as already mentioned in other comments 0 and 1 are 'evident' integer solutions. Probably the reason for choosing this pariticular form of the problem. Replacing 2 by e.g. $1<a\neq e$ you may show that there are exactly 2 solutions but in general you would not be able to describe explicitly the non-zero solution.